# How do i get and count all different numbers in this string

Tags: php, arrays, string, count

So this is what I have :

5335 5335 5290 5335 5245 5245 5245 5290 5290 5290 5245 5245 5245 5245 5245 5245 5289 5289 5289 5289 5289 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317

in this string you see multiple different numbers, how do i count the different numbers and how much there are?

The numbers are over 90 different possibility's

thanks for your time

Comment: Do you get it as plain string or an array?

Comment: its in a plain string, i can change that into an array if that fixes it

Comment: create an array and use `array_count_values()`

Answer (score 2):

```
array_count_values(explode(' ', $string_of_numbers));
```

This assumes that each number is separated by a single space.

[`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/array_count_values)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$str = '5335 5335 5290 5335 5245 5245 5245 5290 5290 5290 5245 5245 5245 5245 5245 5245 5289 5289 5289 5289 5289 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317 5317';
echo count(explode(' ', $str));
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend first using `preg_split` to split the string on whitespace.  This will account for more than one space between numbers

```
$aValueCount = array_count_values(preg_split('/\s+/', $str));
```

This will return an array of each occurrence as the key and the number of occurrences as the value.  For example

```
Array
(
    [5335] => 3
    [5290] => 4
    [5245] => 9
    [5289] => 5
    [5317] => 9
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If as a plain string

```
$string="3414 4564 6513 6351 1713 ...";
$numbers=explode(" ",$string);
//then convert into numbers
for($i=0;i<count($numbers);$i++){
    $numbers[i]=intval($numbers[$i]);
}
//$numbers will now be an array of the numbers that you can do what you want with
```

If it is an array to start with just ignore the first two lines

And `count($array)` is the way t see how many numbers there are